# Why do I see ~$<filename> hidden Excel files?

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, windows-explorer

I have some hidden excel files with the following name format

```
~$<filename>.xlsx
```

[image]

What is the purpose of these files ?
 Is there any harm in deleting them ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why do I see ~$ hidden Excel files?

You have the option to see hidden files and system files enabled on your Explorer settings, you can disable it by going to Tools > Folder options > View Tab > Advanced Options Panel > Unmark *Show hidden files, folders and drives* & mark *Hide system protected files*.

> What is the purpose of these files ?

They are files created by the Microsoft Office suite apps to

1. Save changes temporarily to let you recover your data in case the app or the computer crashes.
2. Act as a *singleton lock* so other instances of the app know that the file has been opened by another user.

They are sometimes left around because either the app was not closed properly, they are normally deleted automatically when changes are saved correctly and there is no data to recover, i.e. when you don't save changes in a while, the *autosave* function will create these just in case, and will be deleted automatically once you properly save your changes. At least this is what I've observed.

> Is there any harm in deleting them ?

No. There is no problem in deleting them, the fact that they're around indicates that something went wrong and there is data to recover and they're normal to appear while the app is running. If you're sure your original file is OK, you can safely remove them.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, I have never had any issues after deleting such files (either in Excel or Word).

From what I have learnt from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3484e5c4-01f9-49c2-afeb-b3ead47023ed/word-document-file-name-starting-with-?forum=innovateonoffice), I understand that they are temporary files created by MS Excel / MS Word when the application crashes or a file is abruptly closed and has auto-save information.

I would suggest cut and paste such files in another location (like external USB drive / hard drive and disconnect them from the PC) and try opening the associated files with similar name. If there are no issues with those normal files - you can delete the files beginning with `$<filename>` from the USB/HDD drive